# how to edit data in R?

Tags: r

```
> edit(data.frame())  

Error in dataentry(datalist, modes) : invalid device
In addition: Warning message:
In edit.data.frame(data.frame()) : unable to open X Input Method
```

my system is: debian6.04+R-2.15.1

what is the matter?

Comment: works as intended for me... you may want to specify a precise editor with the `editor` parameter, or use RStudio instead.

Comment: In `?edit`, it says on UNIX the default data editor is whatever is in `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` if these exist as environment variables in your shell - what are they? (It looks like an X error not an R error - what does `capabilities('X11')` say?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a MAC and just installed XQuartz, you must restart your computer to get the X11 capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It helped

Answer (score 2):

I experienced exactly the same problem on linux and I noticed that it was a problem of input and locale settings. I solved by clearing the following variables in the environment

```
$ export XMODIFIERS=
$ export GTK_IM_MODULE=
```

Then it worked fine.