# Where are the fix() and edit() functions in RStudio Server?

Tags: r, centos7, rstudio-server

I followed the [official guide](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) to install RStudio Server. Everything works fine, but the functions, fix and edit, are not available.

For instance, I have a data.frame called "data" as follows.

```
1,2,3 
4,5,6 
7,8,9
```

The command "View(data)" works fine. But when I execute the command "edit(data)" or "fix(data)", it comes some error messages.

The error messages of "fix(data)" :

```
Error in .External2(C_dataentry, datalist, modes) : 
unable to start data editor
In addition: Warning message:
In edit.data.frame(get(subx, envir = parent), title = subx, ...) :
unable to open display
```

The error message of "edit(data)" :

```
Error in edit : Editing of data frames and matrixes is not supported in RStudio.
```

I ran the same codes on my local rstudio (windows 8.1), and all the functions work fine!
It's really wired... Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

p.s. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009308/cant-use-either-view-or-edit-functions-getting-error-in-external2c-data?answertab=active#tab-top) already, but it doesn't work for me.

sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_TW.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=zh_TW.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=zh_TW.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_TW.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_TW.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_TW.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3
```

Comment: What you show from "data" is not a data.frame.

Comment: Should you be editing the data by hand? Perhaps this feature is turned off for the server edition to save people from themselves?

Comment: @Pascal Sorry, my reputation is not enough to post image XD.
The View(data) looks like this http://i.imgur.com/yFdea0l.png

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You might be right, these functions are a little bit dangerous for beginner (like me), but I dont think the error message of "fix" means security concerns.

Comment: @MarkLee Did you ever find a solution for this? We're trying to use `fix()` on RStudio Server as well, and are experiencing the same problems.

Comment: @Ratnanil Sorry, I didn't find the solution. Now I'm working with Python, so I didn't looking for the solution deeper. If you find any clue, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then I installed the XQuartz package from here: https://www.xquartz.org/

And then another thread, from a while back, reminded me that I needed to restart my Mac for the x11 app to take effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486555

Comment: Your solution is for using R in terminal. This question asks about the Rstudio server (which you typically load it in your web browser on a client computer).